# How does "rem" and "mod" work in matlab?

Tags: matlab, modulus

I understand that both calculate the remainder when dividing two numbers. Mod can compute with numbers that don't have the same value.

However if I had the example:

```
b = mod(23,5)

b = 3
```

How come the answer is three. Whats the math going on behind the scenes to get the value 3?

Comment: What value did you expect it to have? `3` is the remainder of `23/5`, correct?

Comment: Also, I did not understand your statement, "Mod can compute with numbers that don't have the same value." Can you clarify?

Comment: [This link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/16027) might interest you.

Comment: Sorry @beaker, I didn't finish my sentence. I meant to say that Mod can compute numbers with different  signs such as negative or positive numbers.

Comment: If I divide 23/5 that equals 4.6 @beaker

Comment: Oh I get it 5 goes into 23   4 times, which leaves 3 left over.

Answer (score 5):

please consider the MATLAB help

> Note: MOD(x,y), for x~=y and y~=0, has the same sign as y.
>       rem(x,y) and MOD(x,y) are equal if x and y have the same sign, but
>       differ by y if x and y have different signs.

Comment: Wait, seriously? If `x = -20` and `y = 4` (say), I'd expect both `rem` and `MOD` to give `0`.

Comment: @BillBokeey, with how they are implemented, rem: `X - Y*fix(X/Y)` vs. mod: `X - Y*floor(X/Y)`, it seems like another caveat is needed. For opposite signs the difference will be `Y` unless `Y` is evenly divisible into `X`, as in @MarkDickinson's case.